# How to add the returned value from a JavaScript function into an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

This a basic question. But I couldn't find any duplicates on SO.

This is a script I intend to use in my project on different pages. The purpose is to override the default ID shown in a `span` element to the order number from the URL parameter `session_order`. This doesn't affect anything and only enhances the UX for my project.

**scripts.js (loaded in the header):**

```js
function get_url_parameter(url, parameter) {
    var url = new URL(url);
    return url.searchParams.get(parameter);
}
```

**And in my HTML template, I call the function this way,**

```html
<div onload="this.innerHTML = get_url_parameter(window.location.href, 'session_order');">24</div>
```

**Also tried this,**

```html
<div><script type="text/javascript">document.write(get_url_parameter(window.location.href, 'session_order'));</script></div>
```

When the page is rendered, nothing changes. No errors or warnings in the console either for the first case.

For the second case, console logged an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: get_url_parameter is not defined`. But the script.js loads before the element.

Normally, I'd do this on the server-side with Flask, but I am trying out JavaScript (I am new to JavaScript) as it's merely a UX enhancement.

What am I missing?

Comment: span elements don't load external content, so there is no load event for them

Comment: In your second example, you aren't doing anything with the return value

Comment: Can you open the question? I have updated it.

Comment: @quentin, Can anyone please re-open the question? I can't post a new question for another 90 minutes.

Comment: "But the script.js loads before the element" — Either it doesn't, or it has errors in it. Either way, there's not enough information in the question to identify why so it would be closed anyway.

Comment: Can you give me an idea on 'not enough information' part. I did edit the question and update it with more information. I am not sure what more information is needed. Perhaps opening it would help others identify the issue with the code.